# update android spinner value in mysql database

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-spinner, android-ksoap2

hi i have to update my spinner value in mysql database means it is not updated...it shows following error on apache console window.

```
[ERROR] 2
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:639)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

This is my android code:

```
    public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMusketeers);

    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
           unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(unameProp);


              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try{
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                  result.setText(response.toString());

           }
           catch(Exception e){

           }



        }
    });

    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

}

//Add animals into spinner dynamically
private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

 }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This is my webservice code:

```
public class update {

 public String insertData(String status,String username){

  try{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("UPDATE `xcart_orders` set `status` = '"+status+"'  where `status` = 'Q'");
   int result = statement.executeUpdate();
  }

   catch(Exception exc){
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

  return "Updation successfull!!";
  }


}
```

please help me..why my update is not work for me...

Comment: i got the solution...i have small issue here..the issue is:the webservice code pass 2 string status and username..but i have to mention on android code wrongly on dis line unameProp.setName("userName");...now i have replace above line is unameProp.setName("status");...nw i got the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution...i have small issue here..the issue is:the webservice code pass 2 string status and username..but i have to mention on android code wrongly on dis line unameProp.setName("userName");...now i have replace above line is unameProp.setName("status");...nw i got the solutions